# Encryption and unique id

Tags: encryption

Why not encrypt all confidential, sensitive and borderline data? Why not use a fingerprint ID system as the private encryption key? Why not use a fingerprint and/or other unique identifier such as retinal or lens scan to ID your terminal to a computer? Why not use this method of identification to identify ALL info extracting and/or entering devices attached to system (s) that are to be protected?

Comment: Looks rather like an invitation to discussion than like a well answerable question.

Comment: "I, Captain Hook, present my fingerprint... oh, wait!"

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your question basically breaks down to two points: why not use biometrics as an encryption key, and why not encrypt everything, or at least a lot more.

**Security of Biometrics**

> Why not use a fingerprint and/or other unique identifier such as retinal or lens scan to ID your terminal to a computer?

Biometrics are not really all that secure. See for example these links:

- [iPhone fingerprint scanner hacked](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/sep/22/apple-iphone-fingerprint-scanner-hacked)
- [reverse engineering iris scans](http://www.wired.com/2012/07/reverse-engineering-iris-scans/all/)
- [interesting video about biometrics hacks](http://cdn.media.ccc.de/congress/2014/h264-hd/31c3-6450-de-en-Ich_sehe_also_bin_ich_Du_hd.mp4) [in german + english translation]
- [Police can coerce fingerprint to unlock iPhone](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Court-ruling-Police-can-coerce-fingerprint-to-unlock-iPhone_id62374)
- [wikipedia also has a list of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometrics#Issues_and_concerns), including the concern of someone cutting of your finger to get your fingerprint. Is your data really worth this risk?

The main problem is that you cannot keep your biometric information secret, as you leave it all over the place. And once it is acquired by attackers, you also cannot change it.

There are of course other means to get a unique id that doesn't depend on you remembering a password (each with their own problems), such as smart cards, usb key cards, pufs, etc.

**Encrypt by Default**

> Why not encrypt all confidential, sensitive and borderline data?

Who decides what is borderline data and what is not? The easiest solution would be to just encrypt everything. But there are problems with encryption:

- work: someone has to set this up
- speed: encryption takes time
- recoverability: it is a lot easier to recover unencrypted data from failing storage than to recover encrypted data from it
- security concerns: if there is a backdoor in your encryption program or if your system is compromised the encryption is useless, but the other points in this list still matter

Why should someone take on these additional issues if their thread model doesn't really call for encryption? (note that I'm all for encryption, but other people will consider these points)

But it seems that there is a move to encryption by default. It seems to be enabled by [OS X Yosemite](http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/yosemite-filevault/) and [Windows 8.1](http://www.howtogeek.com/173592/windows-8.1-will-start-encrypting-hard-drives-by-default-everything-you-need-to-know/), and [self encrypting drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) do exist.